# Uipath studio- data scraping error appear after I modified the selector

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I use UiPath and `data scraping` activity. First open the browser direct to the e-commerce site and search the product. Everything is fine, until after the product was searched and results were shown, the data scraping stopped and the output gives the following error message which I couldn't understand why:

[image: Error Output]

This is because I had previously edited the selector. Currently, my selector is:

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Qoo10 - &quot;ItemsFList&quot; Search Results : (Q·Ranking)： Items now on sale at qoo10.sg' />
```

My previous selector did not causes any error and the selector was:

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Qoo10 - cooking oil; Search Results : (Q·Ranking)： Items now on sale at qoo10.sg' />
```

The `ItemsFList` is actually a String variable I created. This variable stores a list of text in String format. It stores the exact same text as the rpa input into the search box at the e-commerce site when the rpa begins running.

Comment: Stop the process. Go to the selector. Click on the Validate button. Is the button green there?

Comment: The Validate button is Red colour.

Comment: So that means the selector is wrong. I recommend you to do the UiPath Academy. Creating proper selectors is no super easy thing. Also use the Uipath Explorer to get the best selector and use wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

UiPath tries to write as specific a selector as it can based on the data you provide it. Unfortunately, sometimes that selector is too specific.

For example, when you [scrape a page](https://youtu.be/OLTW85hCF10), it includes the title of the page in the selector. But the page title will change if you are looping through more than one page. And sometimes the page title is completely dynamic, perhaps including a variable that changes every time the page is loaded. If the title is hard-coded into the selector, your program will only work if that page remains constant, which rarely happens.

**Remove the title**

You can use wildcards in the title to make this part of the selector more generic. Quite frankly, my experience is that that title is rarely needed at all, so I just remove it whenever I do a [UiPath web scrape](https://youtu.be/AxWGAEinzG4) of HTML pages.

As you can see in the image below, the title is deselected. You can then click the orange ? Validate button to confirm that the page scraping will still work without the title. If everything goes green, you're good to go.

[image]

As you've found, the title almost always gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your UI selector. It is clear with your error as you can see the title is dynamic and you're relying on the title to find the browser window or browser control. You have to make your selector more generic and than it should work. Try go through the UI explorer or UIPath Documentation. The few options you can try in your selector is:

```
Remove title from the selector <html app='chrome.exe' />
```

Or make Title generic

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Qoo10 - *' />
```

Note the * sign in the title that will make it more generic and please go through their documentation